# How to project this mesh onto a curved object?

Tags: modeling

I need help with a game console I am building. I'm stuck with the text because I can't project it onto the curved cartridge tray. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: you can use the shrinkwarp modifier. [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+shrinkwarp). [Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html)

Answer (score 3):

If the text has no thickness, or if you give it thickness with a *Solidify* modifier, you can give it a *Shrinkwrap* modifier. But in any case it need to have enough topology to be bent.

If it has thickness you can use a *Surface Deform* modifier:

Create a plane, subdivide it (like 30 times), put it under the text. Give the text a *Surface Deform* modifier with the plane as *Target*, click on the modifier's *Bind* button:

[image]

Give the plane a *Shrinkwrap* modifier with the cartridge tray as *Target*, the plane will stick to the surface of the cartridge tray and he text will bend as well:

[image]